# Arcpy ListFields not returning string

Tags: arcpy, convert, esri-geodatabase

I am using Win server 2012 R2 and ArcGIS 10.2.2.

goal: match field names across featureclasses/tables in gdb

I thought that using python to retrieve field names from all featureclasses/tables in a gdb and then convert them to hex would allow me to easily compare and match similar features/tables for a data management exercise. I was wrong.

here's the code:

```
import os
arcpy.env.workspace= r"C:\Users\$user$\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\connection.sde"

feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in feature_classes:
    fieldnames = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    print fc
    for f in fieldnames:
        print (hex(f.name))
```

I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 10, in 
TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex

Print statements are there to help me keep track.
According to esri's [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm). ListFields(fc).name should return a string. However it seems to be a object.

Comment: You can also do `field_names = [hex(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]`

Answer (score 5):

To see that you are encountering a Python rather than ArcPy error try this:

```
print(hex("ABC"))
```

I think you will see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    print(hex("ABC"))
TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex
```

Python cannot convert a string to hex using its `hex` function.

ListFields returns field objects, and from a field object you can get its name as a string by using its `name` property.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo,

thank you for your prompt reply.
I thought this was a Arcpy problem as I was accessing the ListFields objects, not the string within the name object. Thank you for clarifying that.

Python can convert string to hex using some help:

import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\%user$\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\gisview.sde"

feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in feature_classes:
 fieldnames = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
 print fc
 for f in fieldnames:
  for l in f.name:
   print (''.join([hex(ord(l)) for l in f.name]))